# problem in receiving MAC ID broadcast UDP packets

Tags: macos, udp, broadcast, packets

In my case, from a hardware UDP packets are sent to destination PC - 192.168.13.250 (45141) but MAC ID is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF. Now I binded to that destination IP & port no using sockets. But I'm not able to receive UDP packets form PC using socket program. It is not coming out of recvfrom() call. Still it is waiting. If I change the MAC ID to destination PC MAC ID(00-12-d5-f6-3e-92) using hardware settings, then I'm able to receive UDP packets. Without changing the MAC ID, i.e, How to receive UDP packets from broadcast MAC ID. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Following is the log from Wireshark.

- **With following UDP packets are not received** (Wireshark)

Frame 3609 (7978 bytes on wire, 7978 bytes captured)
Ethernet II, Src: 0a:dc:0a:dc:0a:dc (0a:dc:0a:dc:0a:dc), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol, Src: 192.168.13.25 (192.168.13.25), Dst: 192.168.13.250 (192.168.13.250)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: lbc-control (2780), Dst Port: 45141 (45141)
Data (7936 bytes)

- **With following UDP packets are received** (Wireshark)

Frame 3609 (7978 bytes on wire, 7978 bytes captured)
Ethernet II, Src: 0a:dc:0a:dc:0a:dc (0a:dc:0a:dc:0a:dc), Dst: Broadcast (00:12:d5:f6:3e:92)
Internet Protocol, Src: 192.168.13.25 (192.168.13.25), Dst: 192.168.13.250 (192.168.13.250)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: lbc-control (2780), Dst Port: 45141 (45141)
Data (7936 bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 1122 section 3.3.6 states:
"When a host sends a datagram to a link-layer broadcast address, the IP destination address MUST be a legal IP broadcast or IP multicast address."

If you want your PC to receive the UDP packet with a broadcast MAC address, you should also be using a broadcast IP address.